# How to use JWT Authentication with Django for logout?

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, access-token, logout

I have used DRF and simple JWT for the user application and I have tryied make my logout for an application on DRF, but I know how to delete authentication token, I have the blacklist token but the token continues to serve

I want to delete the authentication token, because the refresh-token is in the blacklist token now

Comment: You can't delete a JWT. JWTs are stateless. It's not how you should work with them. If you need to log out users and ensure they can't access your application after logout, then you need HTTP sessions, not access tokens. This is well explained here why you shouldn't use JWTs for sessions: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this setting in settings.py or locally applied at views.py like this

#### this setting is for if you applied globally `JWT Auth`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to add this app "rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist", then run `python manage.py migrate`.It will migrate two new tables and manage blacklisted refresh tokens.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",

    # installed apps
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist",
]
```

The refresh token needs to be set on blacklisted list so that nobody will get access that previous token.

```
 @api_view(['POST'])
    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    @authentication_classes([JWTAuthentication])
    def logout(request):
        """
        Log out all user.
        Args:
            request (HttpRequest): The client's request to the server.
        Returns:
            HttpResponseRedirect: Redirects the user to the Login page.
        """
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # Access the refresh token from request headers or cookies
            try:
                refresh_token = request.data["refresh"]
                #refresh_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', '').split()[1]
                token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
                token.blacklist()
                return Response({'message':'User logout successfully'},status=status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT)
            except (ObjectDoesNotExist, TokenError) as err:
                return Response({'message':str(err)},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid request method.'}, status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```